# Filtering data read from a SQL table based upon user input in a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, datatable

I have a table on a SQL Server that will be accessed by different users.  Each user will be able add and delete rows in the table on the server.

Currently, the form displays the entire contents of the table and all of the rows are editable.  I am trying to allow users to input words or letters into a `TextBox` at the top of the form to filter the rows which are displayed on the form.

1)  I have an event like this:

```
Public Event ValuesChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

And a method like this:

```
Private Sub SearchTxtBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)_
        Handles SearchTxtBox.TextChanged
```

2)  I need to filter based on the user-input from the Textbox.Text.
I would like the filter to be based on each letter entered into the text box.  So, for instance, when you type the letter "A", it would redraw and filter to only show rows that have an "A" or "a".  When you type "Ape", it would do the same by narrowing it further.

Comment: When you say that you have a DataTable on a server, do you mean an actual disconnected, in memory `DataTable` object, or do you mean it's a table in a database on a SQL Server or some other SQL DB engine?

Comment: It's on a SQL Server :)

Comment: What type of control are you using to display the data?  Is it a DataGrid?  Which method are you using for loading the data into the control?  Are you using data binding, or are you loading the data with a DataAdapter or a DataReader?

Comment: I'm using this for the binding/view:  Me.ProgramOwnersBindingSource.DataSource = dataview                  Also I've got this line here that I feel is close:   Dim rowFilterString = String.Format("[Program] contains %{0}%", SearchTxtBox.Text)

Comment: Ok I think I've got it figured out:   `Dim dataview As DataView = _ds.ProgramOwners.DefaultView`                                         

        `dataview.RowFilter = String.Format("Program like '%{0}%'", SearchTxtBox.Text)`    This filters based on the Program Row and the user input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I've got it figured out:

```
Dim dataview As DataView = _ds.ProgramOwners.DefaultViewdataview.RowFilter = String.Format("Program like '%{0}%'", SearchTxtBox.Text)
```

This filters based on the Program Row and the user input :)